# no run function jquery on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I have an animation on scroll page in jQuery, in mobile look wired.

How i can set-up jQuery for not show the animation in mobile browser?
Tin the main.js i have other function that want keep for both browser.

If help this are the animation:

```
$(function() {
    var $elems = $('.animateblock');
    var winheight = $(window).height();
    var fullheight = $(document).height();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        animate_elems();
    });
    function animate_elems() {
        wintop = $(window).scrollTop();
        $elems.each(function() {
            $elm = $(this);
            if ($elm.hasClass('animated')) {
                return true;
            }
            topcoords = $elm.offset().top;
            if (wintop > (topcoords - (winheight * .90))) {
                $elm.addClass('animated');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Put the code that you don't want to run in mobile browsers inside `if($(window).width() >=768) { .... }`

Comment: Hi, thanks! But still not working! è have try to add 

if($(window).width() >=1024) {

    $(function() {
    var $elems = $('.animateblock');
    var winheight = $(window).height();
    var fullheight = $(document).height();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        animate_elems();
    });
function animate_elems() {
wintop = $(window).scrollTop();
$elems.each(function() {
$elm = $(this);
if ($elm.hasClass('animated')) {return true;}
topcoords = $elm.offset().top;
if (wintop > (topcoords - (winheight * .90))) {$elm.addClass('animated');}
}

Comment: You were missing paranthesis - See this - https://jsfiddle.net/7n9zv9xo/